# How to configure font size and color when out.println(string) is used in jsp

Tags: jsp, colors, font-size

How to configure font size and color when we use out.println(string) in jsp? I want print out string which is a data structure that contain some sentences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are generating HTML code, the font size and color are CSS attributes. You may create a `span` tag with a given CSS class name, then in your CSS definition file give it the style you like:

```
out.println("<span class=\"myspan\">This is a sample string</span>");
```

and in a CSS file:

```
.myspan {
  color: red;
}
```